# Show that $S + T$ and $aT$ are linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let  $S:  V \to W$ and $T: V \to W$ be linear transformations. Given $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$, define functions $(S+T): V \to W$ and $(aT): V \to W$ by $(S+T)(v)=S(v) + T(v)$ and $(aT)(v)= aT(v)$ for all $v$ in $V$. Show that $S+T$ and $aT$ are linear transformations.

Comment: where are you stuck with this, it seems quite straight forward from the definitions

Comment: are you sure you want to define $(S+T)(v) = aT(v)$? Because unless $S$ is a linear multiple of $T$, you aren't going to find an $a$.

Comment: There was a typing error from my part, sorry

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: so anyway, where are you stuck? Do you know the definition of linear well?

Comment: Honestly, at the beginning, we already know that (S+T)(v)= S(v)+T(v) and (aT)(v)=aT(v). It looks like the axioms to show wether a function is a linear transformation or not

Comment: I'm lost to be honest

Comment: For a transformation to be linear, it has to be additive and homogeneous. Can you try to confirm these properties with $S + T$ and $aT$?

Comment: What are $(S+T)(v_1+v_2)$,  $(S+T)(bv)$,  $aT(v_1+v_2)$ and $aT(bv)$ where $b$ is a scalar?

Comment: Once you have done this, feel free to answer your own question with the answer :)

Comment: You can do it! I believe in you!

Answer (score 2):

For starters, $(S+T)(u + v) =_{definition} S(u + v) + T(u + v) =_{S,T linear} S(u) + S(v) + T(u) + T(v) =_{Commute} S(u)+T(u) + S(v) + T(v) =_{definition} (S+T)(u) + (S+T)(v)$.

Similarly, $(S+T)(c*u) = S(c*u) + T(c*u) =_{S,T linear} c*S(u) + c*T(u) = c*(S(u)+T(u)) = c*((S+T)(u)).$

Therefore, $S+T$ is a linear transformation.

Can you figure out the rest from here?